# integrating Facebook SDK with cocos2d iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have a cocos2D game with which I would like to add a Facebook share option.
Something very simple in the lines of "so and so solved puzzle number 22 in myGame etc."
I have downloaded and installed the new Facebook SDK and worked with the helloFacebook example.

The problem is that all these samples are written for UIKit and not cocos2D.
I tried to modify the code to make it work with cocos but it started getting complicated.

Is there a way to add simple integration with cocos2D. I don't need anything fancy just sharing to a wall the name of the app and puzzle number solved.

Cheers